# C - Linkage process misunderstanding

Tags: c, linkage

Assume I have header file with a function declaration:

test.h:

```
int func(int a);
```

main.c:

```
#include "test.h"
int main {
    return func(5);
}
```

test.c (without include to the test.h):

```
int func(int x) {
    return x*x;
}
```

I understand why both files compile, but I thought since *test.c* doesn't have an include to the header, the linker won't be able to recognize that this is the implementation, but it did.

- So, why did it?
- Are there any "rules" when I should do include to header files?

Comment: linker knows nothing about the header files but the names. in this case, linker just linked your implementation of a name called `func` and a usage of a name also called `func`.

Comment: Youl should include `test.h` also in `test.c`. This is not necessary, but it will act as a guard if you should modify the `func` function. With the include, `test.c` won't compile anymore, because the `func` in `test.c` doesn't match the declaration of `func` in `test.h`. Without the include, everything will compile and link fine, but during execution you will get undefined behaviour because you call `func` with non matching parameters.

Comment: additonally you should always use include guards or #pragma once

Comment: @MichaelWalz could you explain how the prototype and implementation unmatched? i stared at it and couldn't find any mismatch

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr I didn't write that is doesn't match, I wrote " if you should modify the func function". Maybe that wasn't very clear in the comment.

Answer (score 3):

When linkage takes place, header files are long gone by then. The linker works on so-called *object files*. An object file is compiled from each *translation unit*, i.e. in our case the C-files. Symbols that are not defined within the given object file will be resolved by the linker, which looks at all the other object files and tries to resolve the symbol. 
In our case, `test.c` is compiled into `test.o`, and defines a single symbol: `func`. `main.c` is compiled into `main.o`, which defines the `main` symbol, and refers to an external symbol `func`. Then `test.o` and `main.o` is fed into the linker which (starting from `main`) will resolve `func` from `test.o`.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the help, but there is something else that I don't completely understand. If the linker check between object files - I've tried to do the next thing: header file with declaration of a static function, c file with the implementation, and main calling the function. (in the main - include header file.) I compiled both c files and created 1 object file, and I had linkage error. how that possible?

Comment: `static` means "this symbol is available only in this translation unit". In your case, this meant that the linker was looking for your function exlclusively in main.o, because the symbols declaration was in the headee which was included in main.c. Effectively this meant that main.c had the declaration of a static function without any definition, so the symbol remained unresolved as being static prevented the linker from resolving it from elsewhere.

Comment: Try it with `extern` instead of `static`. Notice how it resolves the linker issue, because `extern` says "this symbol is defined in some translation unit", so the linker will resolve it from the other object file. Why you don't see `extern` all over the place is because it's the default behaviour for functions (but not for globals!).

Answer (score 2):

Header files is only a pre-processor thing. The term you're looking for is [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29) which is a fully pre-processed source file with all headers included. It's this *translation unit* that the compiler sees and uses as input (actually its a little more complicated than this, but lets keep it simple) to create the object files for the linker to use.

The linker knows *nothing* of "header files". Instead it examines the object files, which is in a special format that contains all information needed, like tables of exported symbols and other tables of undefined but referenced symbols, and then the linker uses this information from all object files and all libraries to construct the final executable program.

So in the object file generated from the `main.c` source file, there is a table saying "the symbol `func` is used but not defined here", and in the object file for the `test.c` source file there is a table saying "the symbol `func` is defined here". When the linker looks through the object files, it can match the usage of `func` in one object file to the definition in the other object file.

Answer (score 1):

Header files tell a C source file about shared information. These can be:

- type definitions, such as structures;
- prototypes of functions. The prototype tells what the return type is and what the parameters and their type are. This helps the compiler to check you are using return and parameters of the function correctly. Without a prototype, the compiler will assume the return type is `int` and the function can have any number and type of parameters;
- symbolic constants, created by `#define`s and macros;
- the names and types of global variables.

Including the header file in your compilation units (C source files) helps you to share this information with your compilation units.

The compiler will compile the unit, whether using include files or not, and is left with a number of symbols (variables and functions) that are not in the current compilation unit. In the object file it notes these. Now, when the inker collects all object files to create the executable, it will search in these object files and libraries for the symbols not resolved. If any of these symbols cannot be found, then  no executable is created.

So no, the compiler doesn't need header files.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to understand what the linker is doing, look at its inputs.

Compile `main.o` and `test.o` first. Then examine them with `nm` or `objdump`: you'll see that `main.o` has an undefined symbol `func`, and `test.o` has a defined symbol of the same name.

The linker never sees your code, your headers, or anything except those intermediate object files. Everything it needs is in there, and the only thing it matches is the symbol name and type.

Note that in C, there isn't even any information in the symbol about the function's number of arguments, or their type, or the return value. If you change `test.c` to declare `func` taking two arguments, the program will still link and run - at least, it will start running but may crash. If it survives, one of the arguments will be uninitialized. This mismatch (between `func`'s declaration and definition) is why it's recommended to include the header in `test.c`, so the compiler can catch your mistake before the linker does something stupid.

Answer (score 0):

The linker only looks at the name, `func`. `main.o`requires it. `test.o`provides it. So it works!

But...

**Implementation files should always include their own header!**

I always include the header file in the `.c` file to ensure that the declaration and definition have matching signatures.

Let's say you change the definition and forget to change the header. If you haven't included `test.h` from `test.c` the compiler won't be able to see that the declaration and definitions differ. But when you run your program you will get undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

After so many answers there is not so much to add, and, even if it could seem a little bit off topic, you may want to know about **decorations**.
The **decorations**, or **mangling**, applied to symbols name are used as a simple way to transfer checks from source to object.

MS in C modules, for __stdcall functions, simply adds an `@` sign after regular name followed by the total number of bytes used:

```
int func(char *)   _func@4
int func(double)   _func@8
```

For C++ the mechanism is even stronger, they add to the symbol name some characters representing the type of variable returned from a function, the class, the namespace and which parameters it takes ([see](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ax8kbk1.aspx)).

The result is a 'fully qualified' function name. In this way it very difficult that a wrong symbol is associated to a function.

Answer (score -1):

the linker doesn't really care about headers...

you only need headers to **tell the compiler that main.c can use func()** because WILL be there

the linker just takes all the symbols and puts them into one executable file.

NOTE: this is a simplistic view